# C program to get the values of IP header fields from Linux IP stack

Tags: c

I am developing a program in which i need to know the values of IP header fields inside my program.Since the IP header is of 20 bytes:

```
struct ipheader {

     unsigned char ip_hl:4, ip_v:4; /* this means that each member is 4 bits */
     unsigned char ip_tos;
     unsigned short int ip_len;
     unsigned short int ip_id;
     unsigned short int ip_off;
     unsigned char ip_ttl;
     unsigned char ip_p;
     unsigned short int ip_sum;
     unsigned int ip_src;
     unsigned int ip_dst;
    };
```

Is there any way that i can know the values of these fields 
inside my C program?

Comment: Are you wondering how to parse the fields from an already available packet, or how to capture the packet including headers in the first place?

Comment: I suggest to have a look at [libpcap](http://www.tcpdump.org/) - it should make your life a lot easier.

Comment: the query is that how can i get these system values,since while creating a simple datagram packet (UDP) i fill the SrcIP and port ,DEst IP adress and port and send the packet ,rest of the value are picked by default form the system stack.so i want to know the value of the rest fields eg: ttl,tos etc

Answer (score 1):

Provided your compiler doesn't introduce any alignment blocks within that structure (make sure that `CHAR_BIT` is 8 and `sizeof(struct ipheader)` is 20), you should just be able to include it in your code as-is, and then add something like:

```
struct ipheader *iph = (struct ipheader *)blk;
printf ("TTL = %d\n", iph->ip_ttl);
```

In that code, you will have an IP header pointed to by `blk`, which is probably a `char*`. Casting it to the correct pointer type will allow you to easily access the fields.

The following complete program shows this in action:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <limits.h>

struct ipheader {
    /* 0 */ unsigned char ip_hl:4, ip_v:4;
    /* 1 */ unsigned char ip_tos;
    /* 2 */ unsigned short int ip_len;
    /* 3 */ unsigned short int ip_id;
    /* 4 */ unsigned short int ip_off;
    /* 5 */ unsigned char ip_ttl;
    /* 6 */ unsigned char ip_p;
    /* 7 */ unsigned short int ip_sum;
    /* 8 */ unsigned int ip_src;
    /* 9 */ unsigned int ip_dst;
};

int main (void) {
    char blk[] = {
        '\x00','\x11','\x22','\x22','\x33','\x33','\x44','\x44',
        '\x55','\x66','\x77','\x77','\x88','\x88','\x88','\x88',
        '\x99','\x99','\x99','\x99'
    };
    struct ipheader *iph = (struct ipheader *)(&blk);

    printf ("TTL = %x\n", iph->ip_ttl);
    printf ("sum = %x\n", iph->ip_sum);
    printf ("dst = %x\n", iph->ip_dst);

    return 0;
}
```

Output is, as expected:

```
TTL = 55
sum = 7777
dst = 99999999
```

Comment: basically the structure i provided was for reference, the real query is that how can i get these system values,since while creating a simple datagram packet (UDP) i fill the SrcIP and port ,DEst IP adress and port and send the packet ,rest of the value are picked by default form the system stack.the rest values include ip_ttl,ip_tos etc

Answer (score 1):

Some of those values can be set/retrieved via `setsockopt()/getsockopt()` calls at the `SOL_IP/IPPROTO/IP` level. Consult your OS' documentation (e.g: on Linux `man 7 ip`).

Answer (score 1):

You should use `setsockopt/getsockopt` routines to interface with socket mechanism. These functions are operate on different levels (`IPPROTO_IP`, `IPPROTO_TCP`, etc) and some options are available only for particular socket types (e.g. option `IP_TTL` is available only for `AF_INET` sockets).

get TTL value:

```
int sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_RAW, IPPROTO_ICMP);
unsigned int opt_val;                                                         
unsigned int opt_len;                                                       
getsockopt(sock, IPPROTO_IP, IP_TTL, &opt_val, &opt_len);
printf("ttl %d\n", opt_val);
```

set TTL value:

```
int sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_RAW, IPPROTO_ICMP);
unsigned char ttl_val = 32;                                                                                                                                        
setsockopt(sock, IPPROTO_IP, IP_TTL, &ttl_val, sizeof(ttl_val));
```